# numpy.ndarray subclass with new properties

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a numpy.ndarray subclass that has different properties and more functionalities that are required in my application.
Still I am having hard time assigning the data type on the fly.

```
class Vector(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, value, *args, **kwargs):
        return np.asarray(value).view(cls)

    def __init__(self, value, type=float):
        self.set_type(type)

    def set_type(self, type):
        assert type in (int, float, complex, str), "type can only be int, float, complex or str, %r is given"%type
        self.astype(type, copy=False)
```

this is an exemple showing that the type is not changing

```
a = Vector([1,2,3], type=str)
print a, a.dtype, a.type
>> [1 2 3] int32 <type 'str'>
```

Comment: `astype` doesn't change the object internal type. It returns a copy with the desired type.

Comment: Subclassing `ndarray` is a rabbit hole from which there's no escape.  OTOH, if you *don't* subclass, then lots of numpy functions which branch on whether or not the object is an `ndarray` won't behave the same way.  Conclusion: strawberry milkshake instead!

Comment: Don't get obsessed with making your code fit some design pattern from the Gang of Four. Just give your class a member that is the `ndarray` and move on to interesting problems.

Comment: @Ricardo Cárdenes astype can change the object internal type if copy argument is set to False and order, and subok arguments requirements are satisfied ...

Comment: @Cobry - Only if the requirements are satisfied. They're not in the example you give. Going from an `int64` to a `float64` or to a string, `astype` will return a copy.  You can re-cast the array in-place, but `astype` doesn't do it in the case you're handling.

Comment: @Cuadue The only reason I wanted to subclass numpy.ndarray is because I can apply all numpy array operations directly on the subclass

Comment: @Cobry I guess what we're saying is that subclassing an `ndarray` is an enormous task, but you lose very little (anything?) by saying `Vector.get_array()`. Presumably you will be adding more methods to the `Vector` class so any code that uses that will have to be aware that it's *not* an `ndarray` anyway; and for code that doesn't know anything about `Vector` you can just pass `Vector.get_array()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure your instance is already created with the correct `dtype` in the first place, i. e. during `__new__()`. You cannot change the `dtype` afterwards (apart from creating a new view or copy, but that's not the same instance anymore).

Try this instead:

```
class Vector(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, data, dtype=None, copy=True):
        return np.array(data, dtype=dtype, copy=copy).view(type=cls)

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        assert issubclass(self.dtype.type, (np.number, np.character)), \
               "dtype can only be number or character, %s was given" % (self.dtype,)
```

It will always return a copy of the original data unless both the `dtype` of the original ndarray is the same as the requested `dtype` (or you leave it at its default) **and** `copy=False`.

Note that I put the type assertion into the `__array_finalize__()` method. This is to make sure it will be called in all 3 cases: When creating a new `Vector` instance with `np.ndarray.__new__(Vector, ...)`, when creating a view of type `Vector` from another ndarray and when slicing a `Vector` instance. It will be called automatically by numpy in all 3 cases. If you want to assert that the vector is strictly 1-dimensional, you would put that into this function as well.